# Shell one liner alias howto?

Tags: linux, shell

Here's a small part of my `~/.bashrc`.

```
if [ -t 1 ]
then
    # standard output is a tty
    # do interactive initialization
    # make bash autocomplete with up arrow
    bind '"\e[A":history-search-backward'
    bind '"\e[B":history-search-forward'
fi
```

Now I want to transform this into an alias in one line like this:

```
alias op_prompt="if [ -t 1 ] then (bind '"\e[A":history-search-backward'; bind '"\e[B":history-search-forward'; fi)"
```

It's not the right syntax, and I don't understand when and when not to add the escape character ("`\`").

How make those two `bind` in one `if` and everything in one `alias` in one line?

Comment: Use function instead of alias.

Comment: Use a function, and use the correct delimiters.  To write an `if` statement in one line, the syntax is `if cmd1; then cmd2 ; fi`.  Semi-colons are your friend.

Comment: I need to find a solution so it doesn't change the "basic" login shell, and I still can apply this configuration with one word to type (like alias, but if you have a better & working solution I'm your man

Comment: @WilliamPursell and how about escaping two things: quote `'` and `"`? with one backslash that doesnt work hence my question

Comment: You really can't escape things inside single quotes.  Generally, you mix them by changing the quoting style.  But this becomes a non-issue if you use a function,

Comment: `[[ $- = *i* ]]` would be a better way to test for an interactive shell.

Comment: @chepner Thanks a lot for the tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write a function:

```
op_prompt() {
    if test -t 1; then
        bind '"\e[A":history-search-backward'
        bind '"\e[B":history-search-forward'
    fi
}
```

Comment: can i call it in shell like if it were an alias?

Comment: Yes. To quote the bash reference manual: "For almost every purpose, shell functions are preferred over aliases."  I disagree with that statement somewhat, and would omit "almost".

Comment: Aliases stack better; if you define `ls () { command ls -l "$@"; }`, it is difficult to define your own `ls` function that builds on the first one. But corner cases like that aside, functions are preferable.